# How do I fix my rock, paper, scissors, Arnold code?

Tags: javascript

I've checked this over and researched it all day. The problem is for some reason, I can't get any result except the `string` value for `var result`: `'the result is a tie!'`.

Can somebody look at this and tell me how to fix it so the other string values for var result, when appropriate?

```js
var Terminator = function(choice1, choice2, result) 
{
    var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice <= 0.25) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.50) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.75) {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.99) {
        computerChoice = "Arnold Schwarzenegger";
    } 

    {
        if(choice1 === choice2) {
             var result = "The result is a tie!";
        }

        else if (choice1 === "rock") {
            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                 var result = "rock Wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "paper") {
                 var result = "paper Wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 = "Arnold Schwarzenegger") {
                 var result = "You have been TERMINATED";
            }
        }

        else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                 var result = "rock Wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "paper") {
                 var result = "scissors Wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 = "Arnold Schwarzenegger") {
                 var result = "You have been TERMINATED";
            }
        }

        else if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                 var result = "scissors Wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "rock") {
                 var result = "paper Wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 = "Arnold Schwarzenegger") {
                 var result = "You have been TERMINATED";
            }
        } 

        else if (choice1 === "Arnold Schwarzenegger") {
            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                 var result = "Get to the Chopper!";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "rock") {
                 var result = "Hasta la vista, baby!";
            }
            else if (choice2 = "paper") {
                 var result = "I'll be back";
            }
        } 
    }
  };
    compare(userChoice,computerChoice,Wins);
```

Comment: There is missing somme code: the function compare

Answer (score 0):

`choice1` and `choice2` appear to be undefined from this code here,

if this is true,  you're basically calling

```
if(undefined === undefined) doThings;
```

A simple solution would be change

`choice1` to `userChoice`

and

`choice2` to `computerChoice`

also,  not sure if this is relevant but,  you're defining `computerChoice` as a number,  and then setting it to a string.

Comment: With the undefined varaibles you are ricgt (look at my answer). But the type of the variable computerChoice doesn't matter because JS is a typeless language and converts it, if needed.

Comment: @Sascha Alright, wasn't entirely sure about that, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Sascha Also,  your answer is far superior to mine,  I appreciate the effort you put in.

Answer (score 0):

You use different variables in your code: userChoice and computerChoice against choice1 and choice2.
If you make this compatible it works nearlyfine. The only thinng I do with your code:

- Delete the first row with Terminator and the last with compare, because I don't know for what they are.
- Set choice1 and choice2 correctly.
- Add an alert with the result.
- Remove the else if with <0.99 and use there just an else, because random could be greater than 0.99 but smaller than 1.

.

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice <= 0.25) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.50) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.75) {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} else {
    computerChoice = "Arnold Schwarzenegger";
} 

choice1=userChoice;
choice2=computerChoice;

if (choice1 === choice2) {
    var result = "The result is a tie!";
}
else if (choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        var result = "rock Wins";
    }
    else if (choice2 === "paper") {
        var result = "paper Wins";
    }
    else if (choice2 = "Arnold Schwarzenegger") {
        var result = "You have been TERMINATED";
    }
}

else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
        var result = "rock Wins";
    }
    else if (choice2 === "paper") {
        var result = "scissors Wins";
    }
    else if (choice2 = "Arnold Schwarzenegger") {
        var result = "You have been TERMINATED";
    }
}

else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        var result = "scissors Wins";
    }
    else if (choice2 === "rock") {
        var result = "paper Wins";
    }
    else if (choice2 = "Arnold Schwarzenegger") {
        var result = "You have been TERMINATED";
    }
} 

else if (choice1 === "Arnold Schwarzenegger") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
        var result = "Get to the Chopper!";
    }
    else if (choice2 === "rock") {
        var result = "Hasta la vista, baby!";
    }
    else if (choice2 = "paper") {
        var result = "I'll be back";
    }
} 
alert(result);
```

You got allways the answer "The result is a tie!" because both variables choice1 and choice 2 are (with your code) not instantiated and have so the value null, so that they are equal.